# JPA and Postgres sequence pre-allocation size setup incorrectly

Tags: postgresql, jpa, ejb, sequence, glassfish-4

I am not able to perist any Entity because of a problem with sequence. I use Glssfish 4, Postgres 9.3 + JPA + EJB3 and Netbeans 8.
Below the excpeption:

```
    Finest:   persist() operation called on: MyUser{id=null, email=a@e.it, password=test,         firstname=test, lastname=test, company=Test}.
    Finest:   Execute query ValueReadQuery(sql="select nextval('mom_seq_id')")
    Finest:   Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
    Finest:   reconnecting to external connection pool
    Fine:   select nextval(mom_seq_id)
    Finest:   Connection released to connection pool [read].
    Warning:   Local Exception Stack: 
    Exception [EclipseLink-7027] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
    Exception Description: The sequence named [mom_seq_id] is setup incorrectly.  Its increment does not match its pre-allocation size.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.sequenceSetupIncorrectly(ValidationException.java:1604)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.StandardSequence.createVector(StandardSequence.java:96)
    ...
```

The sequence on Postgres:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq_id
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 27
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE my_seq_id
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON SEQUENCE my_seq_id
  IS 'Sequence for autoincrement id on MyClass';
```

And an extract of my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myuser")
@XmlRootElement
public class MyUser implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="MYSEQ",
                   sequenceName="my_seq_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator="MYSEQ")
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong?
Thanks

I resolved my issue but I don't know why! I saw that the default value of allocationSize() is 50:

```
package javax.persistence;

@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SequenceGenerator {

    public String name();

    public String sequenceName() default "";

    public String catalog() default "";

    public String schema() default "";

    public int initialValue() default 1;

    public int allocationSize() default 50;
}
```

And I have updated my Postgres sequence `increment_by` value from 1 to 50 and now it works!

Comment: If you solved the problem on your own you should delete the question or post and accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the value of INCREMENT from 1 to 50 into my Postgres sequence resolved the issue. As suggested by @unwichtich it is a good idea to specify allocationSize=50 attribute through the @SequenceGenerator annotation.

Answer (score 6):

For reasons beyond my understanding, the JPA spec picked `50` as the default increment for a sequence generator.

PostgreSQL defaults to `1`.

If the two don't match, things get ugly, because JPA thinks it can use values that someone else also thinks they have assigned. At least EclipseLink detects this; Hibernate just goes on merrily trying to re-use already assigned keys.

If your sequence is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq_id
  INCREMENT 1
```

then your mapping must reflect that:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="MYSEQ",
                   sequenceName="my_seq_id", allocationSize=1)
```

I strongly suggest being explicit about the increment, even if you leave it at the default of `50` and alter the PostgreSQL sequence instead. It'll save your and others' sanity when debugging later.

Comment: Initially I specified the allocationSize=1 attribute into @SequenceGenerator annotation having INCREMENT 1 into my_seq_id Postgres sequence, but it did not work. I forgot to mention that I am using EclipseLink.